# How can I plot an XTS frequency plot using R fft / wavelet function?

Tags: r, plot, fft, xts

I'd like to convert the below time-series data with fft or wavelet related function and plot it using R.
Could you let me know

1. How to plot fft or wavelet diagram ?
2. How to extract specific frequency and plot it together with time domain diagram ?

Here is the data :

```
> class(zc)
[1] "xts" "zoo"

> str(zc)
An ‘xts’ object from (10/15/12 09:00:00) to (10/15/12 15:15:00) containing:
  Data: num [1:366, 1] 252 253 253 253 253 ...
 - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  ..$ : NULL
  ..$ : chr "Close"
  Indexed by objects of class: [chron,dates,times] TZ: 
  xts Attributes:  
List of 2
 $ tclass: chr [1:3] "chron" "dates" "times"
 $ tzone : chr ""


> head(zc)
                     Close
(10/15/12 09:00:00) 252.40
(10/15/12 09:01:00) 253.10
(10/15/12 09:02:00) 253.15
(10/15/12 09:03:00) 253.30
(10/15/12 09:04:00) 253.25
(10/15/12 09:05:00) 253.45
```

Thanks in advance,
SK Park

Comment: [Cross-posted on R-help](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2012-December/332144.html).